# Error when invoking "new" method of Unicode::Collate::Locale Perl module on Cygwin

Tags: perl, cygwin

I am using Perl 5.14.2 with [`Unicode::Collate::Locale`](https://wwww.metacpan.org/module/Unicode%3a%3aCollate%3a%3aLocale) on Cygwin to sort some French text

```
use Unicode::Collate::Locale;
my $coll = Unicode::Collate::Locale->new(locale => "fr");
@french_text = $coll->sort(@french_text);
```

The error that I am getting is:

```
Unicode/Collate/Locale/fr.pl can't be found at ./program.pl line 16
```

This error message is being generated from the following file:

```
/usr/lib/perl5/5.14/i686-cygwin-threads-64int/Unicode/Collate/Locale.pm
```

The following file exists:

```
/usr/lib/perl5/5.14/Unicode/Collate/Locale/fr.pl
```

But upon investigation, I noticed that Locale.pm is looking for:

```
/usr/lib/perl5/5.14/i686-cygwin-threads-64int/Unicode/Collate/Locale/fr.pl
```

This file does not exist and therefore I am getting the error message. Is anybody else seeing this problem? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

You should check if `Unicode::Collate::Locale` is installed correctly-

Use command `instmodsh` to check the installed modules.

```
MPBAB:work macpro$ instmodsh
Available commands are:
   l            - List all installed modules
   m <module>   - Select a module
   q            - Quit the program
cmd? m Unicode::Collate::Locale
Available commands are:
   f [all|prog|doc]   - List installed files of a given type
   d [all|prog|doc]   - List the directories used by a module
   v                  - Validate the .packlist - check for missing files
   t <tarfile>        - Create a tar archive of the module
   h                  - Display module help
   q                  - Quit the module
WWW::Mechanize cmd? f
```

Comment: U::C::Locale is part of v5.14.  Actually, I have seen this problem before, more than once, but have yet to track it down.  It is not solely a Cygwin issue, either, since that isn’t where I’ve seen it. I seem to recall it was fixed by doing a CPAN install/update/refresh.

Comment: I reinstalled the module as suggested and the problem is fixed. Thanks for the help.